# How to create a factory that takes references in the initialization with FactoryGirl?

Tags: ruby, factory-bot, factory

I am looking for a way to convert the following to a factory:

```
client = Client.new(application.uid, application.secret, 
                    site:'http://localhost:3000', raise_errors:false)
```

Factory for the application:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :application do
    name         'Test application'
    redirect_uri 'http://another-site.com/redirect'
  end
end
```

The application attributes `uid` and `secret` are not defined in the factory, but upon creation.

The following does not work (`raises undefined method 'application'`):

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :client do
    site         'http://localhost:3000'
    raise_errors  false

    initialize_with{new(application.uid, application.secret, attributes)}
  end
end
```

Comment: try making the `application` accessible to the factory, even passing it as an argument

Answer (score 1):

I think i'm missinterpreting your question, but this code works fine. Might be because I've made `application` available to the Factory as per max pleaner's comment:

**client.rb**

```
require 'factory_girl'

class Application
        attr_accessor :uid
        attr_accessor :secret
end

class Client
        attr_accessor :uid
        attr_accessor :secret
        attr_accessor :extended

        def initialize (uid, secret, extended)
                @uid = uid
                @secret = secret
                @extended = extended
        end
end

application = Application.new
application.uid = 123
application.secret = "secret"    

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :application do
    name         'Test application'
    redirect_uri 'http://another-site.com/redirect'
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :client do
    site         'http://localhost:3000'
    raise_errors  false

    initialize_with{new(application.uid, application.secret, attributes)}
  end
end
```

Code runs fine from console with `ruby client.rb`

Comment: How do you mean by making "`application` available to the Factory"?

Comment: Simply that `application` is in scope to where the Factory is defined. You'll see it further up the code as `application = Application.new`.